# How sets location of HTML,Javascript and CSS files for create a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reference

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dYnqv/

I use that code. I create a folder which names tableEx. Then I put (table.html) and others(folder). In others folder I put (table.js) and (table.css).
Then I opened html file with notepad++ and referenced like that =>

```
<script src = "others//table.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="others//table.css"/>
```

table.css is work but table.js is not. why?

Comment: check whether you have included `jquery` in your script

Comment: You only need / not // in the filenames

Comment: thanks Rahul and jeff but your answers didn't solve the problem. Can you try what I ask? Could you look at the code at link and try that code like me,maybe you find new solutions. Best Regards my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine answers of these two guys. jeff's telling you to replace // for just / and what the other guy is saying is, that the jsfiddle link you took the code from has built-in javascript library called jQuery, in what your javascript code is written in (see the dollar symbol ? it's one of the jquery-specific identifier)

So for your code to work on your computer, you also need to call for this library jQuery, you don't have to download it (but can), simply use some online ones (CDN) by inserting this external js call in html tags, preferably before your js file so it already knows what language it is written in:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adam'sın. It happened. Best Regards.